# Problem with domain Login in Sharepoint 2013 get "domain\\login"on VS

Tags: development

I get a problem if I programming on Sharepoint in Visual Studio I geting a login name with two \\ -- "domain \\login" How to lose one \? Please help.

Comment: it shows two \\ because single \ would mean escape character. It is actually one

Comment: Thanks Arslan, But after migration I don't see same ogranitation. And I don't know why.